# Manually re-render FusionChart in Angular

Tags: angular, fusioncharts

I am using FusionCharts Suite XT v3.16.0 with Angular 8.

I am trying to cause the FusionChart chart to re-render when new data is received.

1. I gave the fusioncharts element in the template a id of "#fc".

   <fusioncharts
   [width]="width"
   [height]="height"
   [type]="type"
   [dataSource]="dataSource"
   #fc

   > 
2. I used the @ViewChild() to obtain a reference to the element

@ViewChild('fc', { static: false })  fc: any;

3. Then I called the render() method on the reference.

   this.fc.render();
4. Although the compiler recognized that a render() method exists on the reference.

At runtime, a failure occurred stating that there is no render() method.

ERROR TypeError: this.fc.render is not a function

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong 'type' of chart for the data provided.